# Keep USB ports powered when suspended

Tags: suspend, release-odin, usb, power

I have recently installed the new Elementary OS 0.6 on my laptop and PC. Before I had Kubuntu 18.04 installed on the laptop, and Elementary 0.4 on the PC.

In both computers, the USB ports ***didn't*** power off on suspension, however, after the Odin install the USB ports tend to power off, forcing me to unplug and plug the USB peripherals in order to get these working again.

This wasn't a problem on a previous version and a similar OS, but it does happen on the current version on both computers.

Is it a change in the Ubuntu 20.04 base, or something connected to elementary OS Odin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On terminal:

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

This will show you every device that may be "awake" during sleep. "On" means awake and "off" is just off. If you want to know what every device is, you can use the command `lspci` and compare the digits.

To switch the state of a device with the name "**XHC**" you need to execute the following:

```
sudo su
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

This will solve your issue. Beware that some tools like TLP or powertop may also modify this settings.

Comment: Assuming I want to use TLP (on my laptop), what should I do in order to prevent it from closing these ports?

Comment: And thanks! I will try it out on my PC and accept it.

Comment: TLP has a specific option to enable/disable USB at shutdown. You don't need to do all of this if you just edit the tlp config file.